# Press a button and thereafter be able to touch on screen and drag a hollow rectangle from (startpoint) until you let go (endpoint)

Tags: ios, swift

When using a drawing program or when using photoshop there is usually the ability to select a rectangle from the buttons panel. There you can press the button and afterwards be able to drag a rectangle on the screen depending on your chosen startpoint/endpoint.

**Class**

```
@IBDesignable class RectView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var startPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero {
        didSet{
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var endPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero {
        didSet{
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if (startPoint != nil && endPoint != nil){
            let path:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: min(startPoint.x, endPoint.x),
                                                              y: min(startPoint.y, endPoint.y),
                                                              width: abs(startPoint.x - endPoint.x),
                                                              height: abs(startPoint.y - endPoint.y)))
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        path.lineCapStyle = .round
        path.lineWidth = 10
        path.stroke()
        }
    }

}
```

**Top ViewController**

+Added class RectView to View(Custom Class)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    let rectView = RectView()

    @IBOutlet var myView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureMoveAround(sender:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

**ViewController**

```
 @objc func panGestureMoveAround(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        var locationOfBeganTap: CGPoint

        var locationOfEndTap: CGPoint

        if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
            locationOfBeganTap = sender.location(in: rectView)
            rectView.startPoint = locationOfBeganTap
            rectView.endPoint = locationOfBeganTap

        } else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended {
            locationOfEndTap = sender.location(in: rectView)
            rectView.endPoint = sender.location(in: rectView)
        } else{
            rectView.endPoint = sender.location(in: rectView)
        }

    }
```

Code gives no particular errors however nothing is happening on screen. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to focus on one issue at a time, however...

1) `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` are for use during design-time - that is, when laying out views in Storyboard / Interface Builder. That's not what you're trying to do here, so remove those.

2) CGrect() needs x, t, width and height:

```
let path:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: min(startPoint!.x, endPoint!.x),
                                                  y: min(startPoint!.y, endPoint!.y),
                                                  width: fabs(startPoint!.x - endPoint!.x),
                                                  height: fabs(startPoint!.y - endPoint!.y)))
```

3) Wrong way to instantiate your view:

```
// wrong
let rectView = RectView.self

// right
let rectView = RectView()
```

Correct those issue and see where you get. If you're still running into problems, first search for the specific issue. If you can't find the answer from searching, then come back and post a *specific* question.

Probably worth reviewing [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm trying to learn a lot in a short time so i'm maybe to eager. I'll read the "How to ask" instructions to better ask questions in the future.